# Remove partitions that appear after GPT format

Tags: usb, partitioning, gpt

I recently formatted my USB to EFI with GPT partition on Windows 10 using diskpart. Since then, even though the USB is not plugged in there are two partitions (empty and useless) that show up among others. Check the image. Can someone guide me on removing them (H: and I:) since they don't show up on Disk Management or diskpart.
[image]

Comment: We need more information.  Specifically from disk management.  Windows does not handle flash drives with partitions, so I suspect, thats half the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have successfully partitioned a flash drive using `diskpart`....

Comment: Have you restarted? What options are there if you right-click on the phantom drives? Is there an Eject option? If so, try clicking it. Also see what Properties shows. You could try re-assigning the optical drives to these letters in disc management, restart and assign back (any drives could be used, but the optical drives are least likely to affect your current system operation).

Comment: @AndroidDev - I didn't say it wasn't possible to put partitions on a removable flash device, what I said, Windows REALLY does not like it.

Comment: Disk Management doesn't even list these drives.
No Eject Option. properties shows used and free space as 0bytes. I tried reassigning using diskpart but get the error, "Virtual Disk Service error: The specified drive letter is not free to be assigned." Even diskpart doesn't see these drives.

Comment: Does not change the fact I need a screenshot, of disk part and disk management, in order to answer your question.

Comment: Here are the screenshots - http://i.stack.imgur.com/O9v57.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0kKw.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I just plugged in the USB that I had converted to GPT. I used diskpart to clean it and create a primary partition. This removed the two phantom drives.

Anyways, I got a question now. What'd I have to do if I had lost that USB? Just a question I had.